# Want to change the orthographic size of Camera at run time if the distance between player and enemy is greater than some value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a Game in unity3d. I am using a mini-map where I want to change the size of my minimap camera with the orthographic feature. if the distance between player and enemy is greater than some value then the size of minimap camera will be greater and if the distance is less than something then the size will be lesser how can I do that in with using mathf.clamp function if we limit camera size to some maximum value?

Comment: `float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, enemy.transform.position); if(dist < 5.0f) camera.orthographicSize = 1.0f;` ?

Answer (score 0):

This video is addressing same problem as you want. Here is the link this will help you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llEJtLuQyPM&index=3&list=PLclF8feY8EKLw5Un6Z2Syt2_35qsdpnHt

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float m_DampTime = 0.2f;                 
    public float m_ScreenEdgeBuffer = 4f;           
    public float m_MinSize = 6.5f;                  
    [HideInInspector] public Transform[] m_Targets; 


    private Camera m_Camera;                        
    private float m_ZoomSpeed;                      
    private Vector3 m_MoveVelocity;                 
    private Vector3 m_DesiredPosition;              


    private void Awake()
    {
        m_Camera = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
        Zoom();
    }


    private void Move()
    {
        FindAveragePosition();

        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, m_DesiredPosition, ref m_MoveVelocity, m_DampTime);
    }


    private void FindAveragePosition()
    {
        Vector3 averagePos = new Vector3();
        int numTargets = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < m_Targets.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!m_Targets[i].gameObject.activeSelf)
                continue;

            averagePos += m_Targets[i].position;
            numTargets++;
        }

        if (numTargets > 0)
            averagePos /= numTargets;

        averagePos.y = transform.position.y;

        m_DesiredPosition = averagePos;
    }


    private void Zoom()
    {
        float requiredSize = FindRequiredSize();
        m_Camera.orthographicSize = Mathf.SmoothDamp(m_Camera.orthographicSize, requiredSize, ref m_ZoomSpeed, m_DampTime);
    }


    private float FindRequiredSize()
    {
        Vector3 desiredLocalPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(m_DesiredPosition);

        float size = 0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < m_Targets.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!m_Targets[i].gameObject.activeSelf)
                continue;

            Vector3 targetLocalPos = transform.InverseTransformPoint(m_Targets[i].position);

            Vector3 desiredPosToTarget = targetLocalPos - desiredLocalPos;

            size = Mathf.Max (size, Mathf.Abs (desiredPosToTarget.y));

            size = Mathf.Max (size, Mathf.Abs (desiredPosToTarget.x) / m_Camera.aspect);
        }

        size += m_ScreenEdgeBuffer;

        size = Mathf.Max(size, m_MinSize);

        return size;
    }


    public void SetStartPositionAndSize()
    {
        FindAveragePosition();

        transform.position = m_DesiredPosition;

        m_Camera.orthographicSize = FindRequiredSize();
    }
}
```